# Native Google Plus Login For Xamarin.Android & Xamarin.iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, google-plus

In Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS is it possible to have native Google Plus login? Ie, login not using a WebForm but the native apps or phone features?

Also is there a plugin or component for this like there is for [Facebook](https://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookandroid)? Looking around this isn't any documentation on native Google Plus login (relating to Xamarin) nor any Xamarin Components.

Comment: I have also been looking for this, but without any luck. Not even Auth0 provides a native way of logging in on Xamarin.

Answer (score 0):

Google Plus login is part of Google Play Services.

I would check out: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/146986 for iOS and for Android the NuGet or component: https://components.xamarin.com/view/googleplayservices

Comment: The second link is dead. It also seems that a component called just "Google Play Services" no longer exists. They all have qualifiers after them. Which one is needed for Google Login?